# Is my processor Intel Pentium D a dual core?

Tags: cpu, multi-core, intel-pentium

My processors is an Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.00GHz. Does the D mean that my processor is a Dual Core?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the Pentium D CPUs are dual core. They are two Pentium 4s on one package.